# QGIS - assign different colors for SVG markers also in categorial / graduated symbols?

Tags: symbology, svg

I understand it is possible to customize the color of an SVG marker via [param(fill)](http://www.sourcepole.com/svg-symbols-in-qgis-with-modifiable-colors)
However, I have to set the color manually, and cannot automatically assign it through categorical or graduated symbols. Is there a way to do this?

As far as I suspect, the color value has to be somehow passed on from the svg marker to the color field for the general marker. If this is not possible, it would be a nice feature.

Comment: It feels like this was overlooked and should be quite easy to add. Please open a feature request at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Please post the link to the feature request here for future reference

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11658